# How to properly use Observable.zip() to combine multiple Retrofit call?

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-android

I'm new to RxJava. My requirement is to do 3 retrofit call at start and wait until all of theme executed. Here is what i had implemented and Its working perfectly but I want know, is this code could be better than this and I implemented schedulers correctly or not.

```
public class CombinedGroupProductPage {
    private List<Product> groupProductList;
    private List<Product> relatedProductList;
    private List<Product> upsellProductList;
    //constructor and getter setters here
    .....
    .....
}
```

> Here is my implementation

```
private void getAllData() {
    loadingProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getRxClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Observable<List<Product>> call = apiService.getRelatedProduct1(gson.toJson(model.getGroupedProducts()))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io());
    Observable<List<Product>> call1 = apiService.getRelatedProduct1(gson.toJson(model.getRelatedIds()))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io());
    Observable<List<Product>> call2 = apiService.getRelatedProduct1(gson.toJson(model.getUpsellIds()))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io());


    Observable<CombinedGroupProductPage> combined = Observable.zip(call, call1, call2, new Function3<List<Product>, List<Product>, List<Product>, CombinedGroupProductPage>() {

        @Override
        public CombinedGroupProductPage apply(List<Product> list, List<Product> list2, List<Product> list3) throws Exception {
            return new CombinedGroupProductPage(list, list2, list3);
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    combined.subscribe(new Observer<CombinedGroupProductPage>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            // loadingProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(CombinedGroupProductPage combinedGroupProductPage) {
            Log.e("Tag", combinedGroupProductPage.toString());
            Log.e("Tag", combinedGroupProductPage.getGroupProductList().get(0).getName());
            loadingProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

        }
    });
}
```

Please tell me this code can be reduced or not? Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Why people down-voting reason please. I'm just saying to review my approach. All tutorial are using old method that were changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Schedulers.io()` instead of `Schedulers.newThread()`. `Schedulers.io()` uses a thread pool whereas `Schedulers.newThread()` doesn't. Creating threads is expensive and should be avoided if possible.

Using `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` for your different calls also allow you to remove the now useless `.observeOn(Schedulers.io())`.

Comment: should i change here too?? `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` on zip obeservable? also tell me above is the right apporach to do this or not?

Comment: in `onNext()` I have to update ui lots of changes there is is okay to do there.. and every observable in this should need to unsubscribe `onDistroy()`

Comment: Yes it is ok to perform your ui changes in `onNext()`. And yes, you should unsubscribe inside `onDestroy()`.

Comment: ok thanks but in above code 4 obsevable sibscribed so everyone needs to unsubscribe on distroy or above 3 can be unsubscribe in `OnComplete()`

Comment: in `onDestroy()` because you might not even reach `onComplete()` in some cases

Comment: one more help need how can i modify this observable to call 2 api or 1 api or 3 api as of my need? in above example every api call happens if there is any method to prevent.?